# Хранение данных сторонних сервисов в базе

Tags: sql, архитектура

Есть некий сервис, предоставляет данные по облачным сервисам, приведу на примере Amazon EC2.
Есть у него регионы и размеры сервера, и собственно эти же данные я храню в своей базе, на начальном этапе разработки вообще не думая просто брал данные и давая им свой PK загонял в базу, выглядит сейчас это вот так:
Таблица провайдеров:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица размеров (`deployment_cloud_id` - это внешний ключ на таблицу выше):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
То есть те ID что давал сервис, я просто назвал `external_id` и всё, но вот теперь вернулась разработка к этим таблицам и иногда получается что пользователь вводит `external_id` или нужно отправить это поле на сервис и приходится идти в таблицу размеров через реляцию или поиском по колонке `id` и брать поле `external_id`, вот думаю возможно стоит убрать локальный `id` и использовать что дает сервис, смущает только то что по всей системе PK `int`, и в нескольких таблицах строчные будут.

Comment: Если он вам где-то нужен, то его можно сразу через JOIN получать там, где и id получаете (в запросе).

Comment: @Visman проблема в том что он только и нужен, и сейчас пользователь выбирает к примеру id = 15, мне нужно идти в базу смотреть что там за колонка external_id и брать значение, вот я и задумался переделать таблицы, валидатор проверил чтобы не было левого значения и сразу в сервис передал и он с ним работает.

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan а что мешает там, где пользователь выбирает, сразу держать нужный Id, т.е. сделать join заранее?

Comment: @Monk это всего лишь 1 из случаев работы с этими таблицами, не хотел просто в сервисе одной сущности вызывать репозиторий другой, но пока решил что так оставлю всё, придётся мокать в тестах это место, чего тоже не хотел.